# Limit Query on $-\infty$ or $\infty$ answer

Tags: limits

Let $f(x)=x+\log_e(x)-x\log_e(x)$
I am confused if I want to know whether $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }f(x)$ is $-\infty$ or $\infty$

I used the following concept $f(x)=x+\log_e(x)-x\log_e(x)$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }f(x)$=$\infty+\log_e(\infty)(1-\infty)$.

After this step I am confused

Comment: $f'<0$ then the function is decreasing for $x>1$.

Answer (score 1):

At an introductory level it is better to keep the discourse within $\Bbb R$ and treat $\pm \infty$ as figures of speech, or abbreviations. For example,  $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ is an abbreviation for $$\forall r\in \Bbb R\,\exists s\in \Bbb R\,\forall x\in \Bbb R\,(x>s\implies (f(x)>r).$$

We cannot do arithmetic on figures of speech. We have to be able to translate them into their complete and precise meanings about actual mathematical objects.

If $x>e^2$ then $(\ln x>2\land x-1>0)$ so  $(\ln x)(x-1)>2(x-1)$.

So if $x>e^2$ then $$x+\ln x-x\ln x=x-(\ln x)(x-1)<x-2(x-1)=$$ $$=2-x.$$

Now, given $r\in \Bbb R,$ let $s=\max  (-r+2,e^2).$  If $x>s$ then $$x+\ln x-x\ln x<$$ $$<2-x \quad \text {(because}\,  x>e^2)$$ $$<r \quad \text {(because} \,  x>-r+2).$$

Therefore $$\forall r\in \Bbb R\,\exists s\in \Bbb R\, \forall x\in \Bbb R\,...$$ $$...(x>s\implies x+\ln x-x\ln x<r).$$ Which  we abbreviate as $\lim_{x\to \infty}(x+\ln x-x\ln x)=-\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

If you use extended reals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations then the expression $\infty+\log_e(\infty)(1-\infty) = \infty + \infty  - \infty \times \infty = \infty - \infty$ which is undefined. So you can't get an answer like this.

However, for any finite $x > 0 $ we have an inequality $ \log_e(x) < x$ so that
$f(x)=x+\log_e(x)-x\log_e(x) < x+ x-x\log_e(x) = x(2 - \log_e(x))$

Now when you let $x \to \infty $ you have $ x(2 - \log_e(x)) =  \infty(-\infty) = -\infty$

So, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }f(x) = - \infty$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = x + \log x - x \log x = 1 + (-1 + x + \log x - x \log x) = 1 - (x - 1)(\log x - 1).$$  For any $N > 0$, $x > N+1$ implies $x-1 > N$, and $x > e^{N+1}$ implies $\log x - 1 > N$.  Consequently, given some number $N > 0$, the choice $x > \max(N+1, e^{N+1})$ guarantees $f(x) < 1 - N^2$, which of course implies $f$ decreases without bound as $x$ increases without bound.

---

Note the only property of $\log$ we have relied upon here is that it is an increasing function that is unbounded above.